# Sort table by group with highest sum and displaying individual entries

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sql-order-by

I have following scenario where i want to order the table and arrange by groups having highest to lowest sum

```
 name   score
----------------
  abc    10
  pqr    9
  abc    7
  pqr    3
  abc    10
  xyz    7
  pqr    7
  xyz    3
  xyz    2
```

now if we observe,

total (abc) = 10 + 7 + 10 = 27

total (pqr) = 9  + 3 + 7  = 19

total (xyz) = 7  + 3 + 2  = 12

How to sort the above table in `SQL` by group with highest sum and it should display individual entries?

```
Expected output:
----------------
name   score 
----------------
abc    10
abc    10
abc    7
pqr    9
pqr    7
pqr    3
xyz    7
xyz    3
xyz    2
```

Comment: MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc?

Comment: Hi Dems sorry i didn't mention it!  Its 'SQLite'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have analytical/windowed functions, so you need to work out the different pieces of data yourself.

```
SELECT
  yourTable.*
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT name, SUM(score) AS score FROM yourTable GROUP BY name
)
  AS totalScores
    ON totalScores.name = yourTable.name
ORDER BY
  totalScores.score DESC,
  yourTable.name,
  yourTable.score   DESC
```

In this query, there is a sub-query. The sub-query calculates the totalScore for each name.

This then lets you put that total score in the ORDER BY clause.  Note, I don't select the total score in my results, you can but it's not necessary.

Also, I've put the name in the ORDER BY.  In this way, if there is a tie with more than one name sharing the same total score, the name that is first alphabetically will be shown first.

Comment: Okie! I would try this and will get back here.. Thanks

Comment: genius.. Thanks. I Think "ORDER BY totalScores.score DESC" was sufficient? Is there need for "yourTable.score   DESC"  please correct me if I am wrong. Also I could not understand "if there is a tie with more than one name sharing the same total score".. in explanation.

Comment: Imagine you have data for ABC of 8,8,8 and data for DEF of 9,8,7.  They both have a total score of 24.  The way I coded the example Guarantees that you get three rows for ABC first, then three rows for DEF.  I have also ensured that the sub-scores are ordered highest first, which was in your example, but whether you need it is up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQL-Server, one way is using `SUM(score)OVER(PARTITION BY name)`

```
SELECT name,
       score,SUM(score)OVER(PARTITION BY name)
FROM dbo.TableName
ORDER BY SUM(score)OVER(PARTITION BY name) DESC,
         score DESC
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/204c4/6/0)

[OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: OP updates says that it's SQLite *(which I think doesn't have this functionality?)*

Comment: @Dems: No, it doesn't. I keep the answer for people on sql-server ;)

Comment: In which case I would consider adding the `name` to the `ORDER BY`.  In the case that two names could have the same value for `SUM(score)` the op is likely to want each name grouped together.  *(Or perhaps also having `MAX(score) OVER()` as a second level tie break.)*